# Sub panel issue

Tags: electrical

At my 100 amp fuse panel I am not getting 120v at all poles.
I removed both 120v feeds and power is present. Second I attacked both feed lines and 120v registers on both fuse bars. Finally I began attaching each fuse and testing for 120v.   I attached a couple fuses and everything registers appreciate until I attached the second breaker on the right sides line and then the complete line went dead. Any suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Pictures of the panel?  Really fuse? Or breaker?

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel please? Is there a main fuse or breaker anywhere in it?

Comment: Are you sure that 2nd breaker you added is proper for this panel? If that caused everything to die, it's likely that this one is incompatible and/or has failed.